# Decreasing a day from date (where date is 1st)in javascript causing date to become zero

Tags: javascript

When I try to decrease a day from the date, the date has become zero instead of adjusting to the previous month date in java script. Below is the example.

```
var dt = new date(2012, 2, 1);
dt.setDate((dt.getDate() - 1));

logger.info(dt.getFullYear()+"-"+(dt.getMonth()+1) + "-" + dt.getDate());

Result is : 2012-2-0
```

Comment: works fine here... sure you don't have a typo in your original code? e.g. you've got `new date()` above, which is not valid.

Comment: For reference/testing: http://jsfiddle.net/8PyFR/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine, I think you're misunderstanding what the numbers are (although I never get `0`). Although you did use `new date(2012, 2, 1)`, but needs to be capitalized - `new Date(2012, 2, 1)`.

When you use: `new Date(2012, 2, 1)`, it creates the date "March 1st, 2012" since `month` (second parameter) is 0 based.

When you subtract a day, it will become "2012-2-29", which is "February 29th, 2012".

```
var dt = new Date(2012, 2, 1);    // March 1st, 2012
dt.setDate((dt.getDate() - 1));

console.log(dt.getFullYear() + "-" + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dt.getDate());    // February 29th, 2012
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8PyFR/3/

You seemed to already understand that `getMonth()` returns a 0-based month, so you added 1. But just as you get a 1-based month (by adding 1), you must accommodate when setting a 1-based month (by subtracting 1). March is normally 3, but you need to use 2.

Comment: I have used cpial D only, it was a typo mistake here. The second step is something like setting zero to date only right? something like this, dt.setDate(0);??